# Insert with on duplicate key update fails without error when auto increment field reached to it max

Tags: mysql, sql

See the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE autoincrement_test (
  ID tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  NAME varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPTION varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  UNIQUE KEY UNIQUE_KEY (NAME)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=255 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE autoincrement_test AUTO_INCREMENT = 255;

INSERT INTO autoincrement_test (NAME, DESCRIPTION) VALUES ('a', 'aaaa') ;

INSERT INTO autoincrement_test (NAME, DESCRIPTION) VALUES ('b', 'bbbb') , ('c', 'cccc') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE DESCRIPTION = VALUES(DESCRIPTION);
```

The last statement should fails since the auto increment field reached max value, but it does not.

If I would remove the `on duplicate` part it will fail.

Using mysql 5.6.40

Comment: *"The last statement should fails since the auto increment field reached max value, but it does not."* i think `INSERT INTO autoincrement_test (NAME, DESC) VALUES ('b', 'bbbb') , ('c', 'cccc') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`DESC = VALUES(DESC);` **updates** existing data here in this case which does not require `AUTO_INCREMENT` again.. But hard to know for sure without knowing the data in the tables.

Comment: To confirm mine comment can you post a complete user case (including the other 255 inserts) on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) .. If you connect with a client (mysql cmd client for example) which is able to make a ascii table from the data.. db-fiddle can parse that format into `INSERT` queries. see the blue "text to DDL" button  in left corner below.

Comment: No need to insert other records, it is perfectly fine that the table will include a single record with auto id that reached the maximum (imagine that we delete all other records), just try this sample code

Comment: _Small Note_ The CREATE Table fails because `DESC` is a reserved word. You would have to wrap that word in backticks to make it work

Comment: And all the other command fail for the same reason

Answer (score 0):

This behaves as expected.

Consider:

```
CREATE TABLE autoincrement_test (
  ID tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  NAME varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `DESC` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  UNIQUE KEY UNIQUE_KEY (NAME)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=255 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE autoincrement_test auto_increment = 255;
INSERT INTO autoincrement_test (NAME, `DESC`) VALUES ('a', 'aaaa');
INSERT INTO autoincrement_test (NAME, `DESC`) VALUES ('b', 'bbbb');
```

This generates the following error:

> ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '255' for key 'PRIMARY'

Which is basically what you would expect.

Now if you add `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to the last `INSERT` statement, no error is generated, and the table content is now:

```
| ID  | NAME | DESC |
| --- | ---- | ---- |
| 255 | a    | bbbb |
```

**[Demo on MySQL 5.6 DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pZkDK7RdNfuUy7G5f2Tqgb/0)** (you can comment the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause to generate the error).

NB: `DESC` is a reserved word in MySQL (and in most other RDBMS, hence it needs to be surrounded with backticks).

Comment: Thanks GMB for the detailed answer, so you agree that in case I use the "on duplicate key update" I'm in a risk that auto increment will reach its maximum value and it will return success even if it actually did not.
Is this a known bug in mysql ?